# Message shows when user is logged in

Tags: magento2, javascript, css

I want to show a message in a  when the user is logged in under customermenu.phtml, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Get customer session anywhere and add your content as below

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create(‘Magento\Customer\Model\Session’);
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) { //customer is loggedin or not
//add your content here
}
```

(OR)

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$context = $om->get(‘Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context’);
$isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
if($isLoggedIn){
//add your content here
}
```